# mod_rewrite causes apache to crash with Rewritemap prg directive

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

Apache configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLock /var/www/lib/rewrite.lock
RewriteMap sessionValid prg:/var/www/lib/allow.php
```

I fixed the obvious of setting the file executable, but now it is giving this:

> [Fri Feb 12 01:55:31 2010] [error] (2)No such file or directory:  exec
>   of '/var/www/lib/allow.php' failed

But the file clearly exists.

Answer (score 0):

...Forgot to make allow.php executable for the apache user.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Yaroslav Erm, it looks like it provides an answer to the question to me, even if it isn't verbose (and the question isn't particularly helpful to anyone in the future given what the problem was). Not sure what your objection is.